# Including files

Tags: php, file

Ok guys, i was wondering: How could i access every file by every file in the same way.
I mean, let's say i have this folder & files schema:

```
A/index.php
A/B/file1.php
A/B/famous.php
A/B/C/file2.php
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

index.php

```
include('B/famous.php');
```

file1.php

```
include('B/famous.php');
```

file2.php

```
include('B/famous.php');
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include it trough an absolute path.
Or make a config file what defines this absolute path, and put it in the root

so you'd do

```
include('/config.php');
include(BASEPATH.'B/famous.php');
```

config.php would have something like this in it

```
define(BASEPATH, "/var/www/myDomain/mySite");
```

Comment: it's $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: You could use that indeed (you can echo it in a test.php file for instance

Answer (score 1):

Add `/path/to/A/B` to your PHP installation's `php.ini` `include_path` directive.

Comment: How could i get the right path? I mean, the folders behind A?

Comment: @Charlie: You can simply do `set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__).PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path())` in your index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Give each root file a variable `$root_path = ../;` (changed corresponding to the level the script is at, then your include statement will look like `include($root_path . "B/famous.php");`